# Understanding segmentation faults in references when popping from queue

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, queue

I've got the following function:

```
std::vector<Node> BFS(Graph g, Node source, Node target) {
    std::queue<std::vector<Node> > q;
    std::vector<Node> path = {source};
    q.push(path);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        std::vector<Node> cur_path = q.front();
        q.pop();
        Node cur_node = cur_path[cur_path.size() - 1];
        if (cur_node.data == target.data) {
            return cur_path;
        }
        // for (int i = 0; i < g.edge_map[cur_path].size(); i++) {
        //     std::vector<Node> new_path = cur_path;
        //     new_path.push_back(g.edge_map[cur_path][i]);
        //     q.push(new_path);
        // }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm not claiming this accomplishes a search at the moment, I just want to know why it causes a segmentation fault. I know it's because I've got that q.pop(); bit, but why? Is this because vectors are inherently references? I can include more of my code if needed, just trying to encapsulate the issue at hand.

EDIT: here's the main() driver:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // double normals[][3] = {
    //    #include "normals.txt"
    // };
    Graph g;
    Node n0 {0, "red"};
    Node n1 {1, "yellow"};
    Node n2 {2, "black"};
    Node n3 {3, "black"};
    Node n4 {4, "red"};
    Node n5 {5, "yellow"};
    Node n6 {6, "black"};
    Node n7 {7, "black"};
    Node n8 {8, "red"};
    Node n9 {9, "yellow"};
    Node n10 {10, "black"};
    Node n11 {11, "black"};

    g.add_neighbor(n0, n1, true);
    g.add_neighbor(n0, n2, true);
    g.add_neighbor(n0, n3, true);
    g.add_neighbor(n2, n4, true);
    g.add_neighbor(n4, n5, true);
    g.add_neighbor(n4, n6, true);
    g.add_neighbor(n4, n7, true);
    g.add_neighbor(n6, n8, true);
    g.add_neighbor(n8, n9, true);
    g.add_neighbor(n8, n10, true);
    g.add_neighbor(n8, n11, true);
    BFS(g, n0, n11);
    return 0;
}
```

which gives:

```
graph. yup
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

FWIW, my graph has an edge_map member which is a map with Node structs as keys, and vectors of Node structs as values to represent a graph adjacency list. The constructor outputs the 'graph. yup' bit, please let me know if you need more information

EDIT 2: I'm just going to include the rest of it for completeness, sorry for verbosity but I'm trying to understand why this is happening.

graph.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

struct Node {
    int data;
    std::string color;
};

inline bool operator<(const Node & left, const Node & right) {
    return left.data < right.data;
}

class Graph {
public:

    std::map< Node, std::vector<Node> > edge_map;

    Graph();

    void add_neighbor(Node cur_node, Node new_node, bool both_ways=false);

    void remove_neighbor(Node cur_node, Node del_node, bool both_ways=false);

    void print_neighbors(Node cur_node);

    virtual ~Graph();
};
```

graph.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "graph.h"
#include <map>

Graph::Graph() {
    std::cout << "graph. yup" << std::endl;
}


void Graph::add_neighbor(Node cur_node, Node new_node, bool both_ways) {
    edge_map[cur_node].push_back(new_node);
    if (both_ways) {
        edge_map[new_node].push_back(cur_node);
    }
}

void Graph::remove_neighbor(Node cur_node, Node del_node, bool both_ways) {
    // TODO: convert vector values in map of <Node, vector<Node> > into maps, so this function can be easy and have sensible complexity
    std::cout << "Not implemented yet." << std::endl;
    // if (both_ways) {
    //     edge_map[del_node].remove(cur_node);
    // }
    //this->edge_map[cur_node].erase(std::remove(this->edge_map[cur_node].begin(), this->edge_map[cur_node].end(), del_node), this->edge_map[cur_node].end());
}

void Graph::print_neighbors(Node cur_node) {
    for (int i = 0; i < edge_map[cur_node].size(); i++) {
        std::cout << edge_map[cur_node][i].data << " " << edge_map[cur_node][i].color << std::endl;
    }
}

Graph::~Graph() {
    std::cout << "ded graph :(" << std::endl;
}
```

any general tips are also appreciated, I'm green as hell.

Comment: There isn't a single reference in your code. Can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: That's what I thought, but there's no question on SO that doesn't talk about references with respect to this specific issue with STL queue pop() causing segfaults, at least not that I can find. I'll edit some info in.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or you won't get much help.

Comment: Included probably too much, but hopefully I can understand what's going on now

Comment: C++ in general is not friendly to bad logic. Pop an empty `queue`? Well you shouldn't do that, so C++ isn't going to slow the billions of good pops just to prevent one bad pop. `cur_path[cur_path.size() - 1]` is just waiting to execute on an empty `cur_path`. Nothing will prevent this from happening except you.

Comment: @ILoveCliques: that's not minimal

Comment: Or complete.321

Comment: @user4581301 but the pop only occurs if the queue isn't empty, and the front() as well so cur_path can't be empty unless there's bad data in the queue, which isn't the case in this example. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying though

Comment: @ILoveCliques Your `BFS` function fails to return anything if that `while` loop doesn't return that value in the `if (cur_node.data == target.data)` statement.  Thus your program will have undefined behavior if that `if` is always `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big, glaring error:

Your `BFS` function does not return a value for all control paths, even though it's supposed to return a `std::vector<Node>`.  Thus your program has undefined behavior.  The only path where `BFS` returns is in the conditional statement in the `while` loop:

```
 if (cur_node.data == target.data) {
            return cur_path;
```

However no return is done if the `cur_node.data` is never equal to  `target.data` during the running of the outer `while` loop, thus triggering the undefined behavior (in your case, a segmentation fault).

Running your program [here, using the triggering output statement, "I'm in trouble!!"](http://rextester.com/NCUB22944) shows you are causing undefined behavior.  Note that the compiler used is Visual Studio 2015.

But to show the ramifications of undefined behavior, note that `gcc` [as shown here](http://ideone.com/nz5uVi) will just crash without printing the message.  To have it print the message, the buffer has to be flushed with `std::endl` to see the  "trouble!!" string [as seen here](http://ideone.com/ZsILP7).

Given all of that, since you have to return something, you have to decide what to return in the case of the node not being found.  You could return a `std::vector<Node>()`, but how would the caller to `BFS` determine if this node is a node that exists or not?  I think you need to straighten out the ground rules for `BFS` as to what the output of that function should denote.

Also:

```
Node cur_node = cur_path[cur_path.size() - 1];
```

could simply be:

```
Node cur_node = cur_path.back();
```

Answer (score -1):

(I have not enough reputation to add a comment)

As far as I understand what might be happening:

- q.pop invokes destructor of std::vector
- ~std::vector destroys each Node
- Maybe the Node destructor does something illegal?

Comment: Best suggestion is just don't. Posting weak answers slows down your ability to earn commenting rights.

Comment: And now that new information has arrived, `struct Node {
    int data;
    std::string color;
};` finds the answer incorrect.

Comment: gdb bt gives:

#0  0x00007ffff7b240c0 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0000000000402566 in Node::~Node() ()
#2  0x0000000000403035 in void std::_Destroy<Node>(Node*) ()
#3  0x0000000000402e10 in void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<Node*>(Node*, Node*) ()
#4  0x0000000000402bc2 in void std::_Destroy<Node*>(Node*, Node*) ()
#5  0x00000000004024aa in void std::_Destroy<Node*, Node>(Node*, Node*, std::allocator<Node>&) ()
(cont'd in next comment)

Comment: #6  0x0000000000402c25 in std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> >::~vector() ()
#7  0x00000000004040e2 in main ()

Comment: @ILoveCliques Right, but that's not a problem with the destructor. That's because the node being destroyed doesn't exist.

Comment: @user4581301 Are you saying it's better to create shared ptrs to nodes, instead of how I'm currently initializing them?

Comment: "any general tips are also appreciated, I'm green as hell." So am I. Anyway, the bt shows something's gone wrong with std::string destructor, doesnt it? (I'm not so familiar with debugging) Could you replace the type of node::color with 'const char*' without breaking your code - just to see if it still segfaults?

Comment: @ILoveCliques Shared pointers fill a particular niche. You have the right idea here allowing the container to manage the memory, but somewhere in the call to `BFS` a copy is going wrong and to be honest I don't know where. What I do know is this address: 0x00007ffff7b240c0 is wrong, which usually means a `this` pointer got whacked, which in this case means a node is wrong, which means that a pointer in a vector isn't pointing where it should.

Comment: @elrat yes, the string destructor tried to free invalid memory. How does a string contain a pointer to invalid memory? memory overrun or the whole string is bad are typical candidate. In this case the string is bad because the node containing it is bad because the vector is bad. I'll have to take a closer look to see why, but I'm lacking in tools at the moment.

Comment: @ILoveCliques Fork, I'm stupid. There is no return statement in `BFS`. The compiler isn't able to make a function that operates correctly. For an experiment add `return std::vector<Node>();` to the end of BFS. It won't do anything useful, but the compiler should be able to generate correct code.